# Xcode 7 error. Missing required architechture when building

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to build my project I get the following errors (see below)

Some info

IOS7 target

Upgraded to xcode 7. But I did experience issues in xcode 6 also

BaseSdk IOS9

Pods installed. But since my project is targeting IOS7 I can't use use_frameworks

The code works on my colleagues machine

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jvk/Code/*****/Security.framework/Security, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/jvk/Code/****/Security.framework/Security (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_SecCertificateCopyData", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecCertificateCreateWithData", referenced from:
      +[FABCertificatePinner createCertificationWithData:length:] in Fabric(FABCertificatePinner.o)
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      -[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _FABCertificateWithData in Fabric(FABCerts.o)
  "_SecPolicyCreateBasicX509", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      -[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecPolicyCreateSSL", referenced from:
      -[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustCopyPublicKey", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from:
      -[FABCertificatePinner evaluateTrust:result:] in Fabric(FABCertificatePinner.o)
      _AFPublicKeyForCertificate in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFServerTrustIsValid in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:
      _AFCertificateTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
      _AFPublicKeyTrustChainForServerTrust in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates", referenced from:
      -[FABCertificatePinner evaluateTrust:result:] in Fabric(FABCertificatePinner.o)
      -[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
  "_SecTrustSetAnchorCertificatesOnly", referenced from:
      -[FABCertificatePinner evaluateTrust:result:] in Fabric(FABCertificatePinner.o)
  "_SecTrustSetPolicies", referenced from:
      -[AFSecurityPolicy evaluateServerTrust:forDomain:] in libPods.a(AFSecurityPolicy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues and already have those frameworks linked. Followed this steps: https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-and-fabric-will-not-link-properly/38112/2 and some errors went away but this one keeps poping up.

Answer (score 3):

I had tried migrating to Fabric by dragging the suitcase icon across as they suggested. After this failed to work, I went down the Cocoapods route for updating Crashlytics and adding Fabric to my app. I was getting the same error message here.

Turned out, when I attempted to drag Fabric across earlier, I kept the radio button for copying all items to local selected - when you do this, it copies a  local `Security.framework` file across too. It was this version of `Security.framework` being referenced by my target, which apparently causes this issue as they conflict, which produces the same error as if it wasn't referenced at all.

When I removed this from `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`, and deleted it from the project and moved to trash, then re-added `Security.framework` properly, this error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Add the Security.framework to your target in `Link Binary with Libraries` and build

Answer (score 0):

Try adding x86_64 as an architecture to build for and set it to always build for all architectures.
[image]

Comment: We tried it, but unfortunately it did not fix the issue. But thanks for the input.